# laravel vue SPA page returning HTML instead of json value on ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, vue.js, single-page-application

This is my ajax request from Vue page .

```
AuthenticationServices.checkEmail(this.userData.email).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.data == 1) {
        this.errored = true;
    } else {
        this.errored = false;
        this.successInput = true;
    }
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

and this is the code in AuthenticationService.js

```
checkEmail(email) {
    const url = '/check-email' + '/' + email;
    const headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'X-Requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
    return Api.get(url, headers);
}
```

and this on Api.js

```
get(url, headers = {}) {
    url = this.prepareUrl(url);
    const options = {
        headers: headers
    }
    return axios.get(url, options);
},
prepareUrl(endpoint) {
    let baseUrl = '127.0.0.1:8000/api';
    return baseUrl + endpoint;
}
```

and this is my web.php which renders all the pages

```
Route::get('/{any}', function () {
  return view('welcome');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

and in Api.php  i have route for checkEmail

```
Route::get('/check-email/{$email}', 'Frontend\Authentication\AuthenticationController@checkEmail')->name('check-email');
```

and in controller , i have

```
public function checkEmail($email)
{
    return response()->json('ok');
}
```

and when i hit that route . it is returning like this 
[image]

The response should be 'ok' . i cant figure out the problem ..

Header section 
[image]

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: laravel versio 5.8.*  and vue ^2.6.10

Comment: Please can you add the code for your `prepareUrl()` method.

Comment: Did you prefix the api call with `/api`?

Comment: ```
 prepareUrl(endpoint)
    {
     
        let baseUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api';
        return baseUrl+ endpoint;
    } ```

Comment: @PtrTon yes i have done it .

Comment: Lastly, please may you take a screenshot of the `Headers` section in your network tab for the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a dolar sign in the route where there shouldn't be one.

try changing {$email} to {email}

Comment: OMG man .. how could i be so careless...... It worked .. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The header seems to be Ok, so to avoid this add a condition in your web routes :

```
Route::get('/{any}', function () {
  return view('welcome');
})->where('any', '^(?!api).*');
```

This should tell laravel to use api routes instead.

Comment: Nope , didnt work. it throws Route not found error.